# Antonym of "dispenser"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, antonyms

I've been searching a lot of dictionary websites for the antonym of *dispenser*.  I was wondering if anybody could think of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps also *withholder* or *inhibitor* in the sense that a dispenser allocates/distributes/gives and a withholder or inhibitor would hold back or keep.

Answer (score 4):

**Collector** works in many situations; one person dispenses information, another collects it.

Answer (score 1):

**Receiver** or **taker**, I would say. Maybe even **recipient** or **acceptor**.